# Remove last column values in field seperated file using unix shell script

Tags: bash, unix, shell-script, bash-scripting

The files is seperated by | pipe symbol

myfile.txt

```
Hello|how|are|you|hope|you|are|doing|fine
Lilly|jasmine|rose|sunflower|nightfire|flowers
```

I want to remove columns greater than 3. I want result set as

```
Hello|how|are
Lilly|jasmine|rose
```

In actual file i have to remove the extra columns more than 13 columns in each row. Using SED/AWK in unix shell scripting. Thanks !

Comment: Why using sed or awk? `cut`ting fields off feels for a task for cut (e.g. `cat testfile | cut -d\| -f 1-3`). And why not in a shell script? Or did you mean awk, sed or bash. Or any shell?

Comment: Also, is it either remove colums "greater than 3" or "more than 13". Both cannot be right.

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -d'|' -f1-14 myfile
```

This works fine! Simple cut would do no need for awk or sed.

Comment: need missing "space" between -f and first index; and should be `-f 1-3` to produce requested output, but definite +1